# Throughput of Bluetooth LE Device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, throughput

Based on this link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy

Bluetooth Low energy device has a throughput of 
0.27 (Mbit / s) = 276.48 Kbit / s.

But on the actual i am able to do only 20 bits of data "p 2?>sp 2STS2000 v2." this is the sample bit of data that is actually transferred.

### Observation:

The number of characters that can be read from the peripheral is 20

### Inference

So if the actual bytes read is exactly 3 bytes then, 24 bits of data is got.
Out of the remaining 4 bits one byte could be for the header and the remaining
3 bits for the checksum.

is this the correct?

Comment: If you're worried about throughput, you're probably doing it wrong.  BLE's whole purpose is to exchange throughput for power savings.  If you try to get the highest throughput in BLE you won't get much battery savings and should probably just use regular Bluetooth (which is much faster).

Comment: There are so many wrong things in your "inference" paragraph I honestly don't know what to start with. I'm just letting you figure it out.